# iOS 14 Wrong Keyboard size

Tags: swift, ios14

I am getting wrong keyboard frame when I switch orientation from landscape to portrait.
This is how I am getting the keyboard frame.

```
let value: AnyObject = (note as NSNotification).userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject
        return view.convert(value.cgRectValue, from: nil)
```

And I am still getting the frame for the landscape mode. This issue is only on iOS 14.

Comment: This is not relevant to your question, but this is not good code. You are basically writing the whole code in Objective-C even though your language is Swift. You should not be using AnyObject, NSNotification, or `cgRectValue`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe from converting frame to view
Try to get frame without converting it like this, it works for me
Also check the notification type, for me I'm using **UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification**

```
    let keyboardframe = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue 
    return keyboardframe
```

Comment: The problem is with this keyboard frame like you are getting.
Its changed. Have you tried with changing orientation. Issue happens when I come back from landscape to portrait. and its on ios 14

Comment: Yes I checked before I answered, it's recalling notification with the new keyboard frame.
Try using exactly the same code and don't use "view.convert(value.cgRectValue, from: nil)"

Comment: As I have already said above. The change is in the keyboard framework

let keyboardframe = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIApplication.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change shouldAutorotate to return true

```swift
    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        get {
            return true 
        }
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        get {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    }
```